How to keep VMs sorted alphabetically in VMware ESXi vSphere?
Every time you login to the vSphere web client and click VMs, the list displays in a random order (possibly in the order in which they were added).
You have to remember to sort them A-Z. Sometimes if you're not paying attention, VMs with similar names can appear in the place of where you'd usually expect to see another (when sorted A-Z).
How can we permanently keep the list of VMs sorted alphabetically?
I am talking about in ESXi/vSphere on each individual server, not in vCenter.
I looked online and the answer does not appear to be readily apparent.
Here's an example screenshot of a VM list from another user:


AFAIK this is not possible. You could start a feature request, but with VMware going downhill I wouldn't get my hopes up.

Best chances are probably to implement a browser script.

If anybody wants to go deeper, after a cursory inspection of some ESXi hosts I have the impression that they are sorted in the order the VMs were created on the datastore. If that is the case a "solution" could be to move the VMs to a different datastore in alphabetical order. With the filesystem being vmfs I don't see any way to modify the birth time of the directories in any other way.

there is also a other possibility using 00001 and go up works fine for me but i aint sure if one of my plugins push this usage out

Here's a Tampermonkey userscript I wrote:
// ==UserScript==
// @name         ESXi - Keep VMs sorted alphabetically
// @namespace    http://serverfault.com
// @website      https://serverfault.com/questions/1157687/how-to-keep-vms-sorted-alphabetically-in-vmware-esxi-vsphere
// @version      0.2.0
// @description  When the VMs list in ESXi loads, this script will sort them alphabetically - you're free to sort them yourself afterwards!
// @author       Public domain
// @match        https://123.45.67.89/ui/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=vmware.com
// @grant        none
// @require      https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    var $ = window.$;

    function fire(e) {
        if(window.location.hash !== '#/host/vms') {
            return;
        }

        // Wait for the list of VMs to load
        var loop = setInterval(function() {
            var vms = $('.k-grid-content table tbody').eq(0);

            if(vms.children().length > 0) {
                clearInterval(loop);

                var languages = ['Virtual machine', 'Machine virtuelle', 'Máquina virtual', 'Virtuelle Maschine', 'Macchina virtuale', '虚拟机', '虛擬機器', '가상 시스템', '仮想マシン'];
                $(languages).each(function(index, value) {
                    $(`esx-vm-list th[data-title="${value}"`).click();
                });

                console.log('✅ Sorted VMs alphabetically!');
            }
        }, 100); // ms
    }

    fire();
    $(window).on('hashchange', fire);
})();

Replace 123.45.67.89 with your server's IP address or whichever address you access ESXi on.
You can use wildcards like 123.45.67.* or you can duplicate the line for additional hosts, per the Tampermonkey documentation.
It could do with using the local jQuery instead of downloading it from the web (ESXi does use jQuery already, which you can access via $ in the console, without the userscript).
If you want to edit this answer with a solution to this then please do - it is a Community Wiki 

Just invoking $('th[data-title="Virtual machine"]').click() on page load should suffice to trigger the builtin sort mechanism.

@GeraldSchneider Nice, thank you! I edited the answer and made it CW - I also added localisation support for all of the languages that ESXi supports, so that it still works no matter which language you have selected. I also limited it to <esx-vm-list>.

not sure why you're getting downvoted.
But..Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in feature in VMware ESXi vSphere to permanently keep the VM list sorted alphabetically by default.
